# how to implement amazon webservice in android app

Tags: android, web-services, soap, amazon-web-services

How to implement amazon webservice in android

```
public void startTask()
{
    new AsyncService().execute();

}


    protected void onPreExecute() {                          
        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            postLoginData();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex.getMessage();
        }   

        return null;


    }


     protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

            Dialog.dismiss();

            String OutputData = "";
            JSONObject resultObj = null;

            if(Content == null || Content.length() <= 0)
            {
                mdelegate.onErrorResponse("We are not able to connect with server, please try later");
                return;
            }

            try {
                resultObj = new JSONObject(Content);
                boolean status=resultObj.getBoolean("Status");
            if(status)
                {

                    JSONArray basketItemArr = new JSONArray(Content);

                    ArrayList<BasketItem>  itemList=new ArrayList<BasketItem>();

                    for (int index=0;index<basketItemArr.length(); index++) {

                        JSONObject itemObj=basketItemArr.getJSONObject(index);

                        BasketItem baketItem=new BasketItem();

                        baketItem.setId(itemObj.getString("item Id"));
                        baketItem.setDescription(itemObj.getString("itemDescription"));
                        baketItem.setTitle(itemObj.getString("Item Name"));
                        baketItem.setItemIconStr("image/apple.png");
                        baketItem.setItemPrice(itemObj.getString("Item Icon"));
                        baketItem.setItemOferPrice(itemObj.getString("itemOffer"));
                        baketItem.setImageIconUrl(itemObj.getString("Item Icon"));
                        itemList.add(baketItem);



                    }

                      mdelegate.onSuccessfullResponse(itemList);
                }
                else
                {
                    String errorMsg=resultObj.getString("Message");
                    mdelegate.onErrorResponse(errorMsg);
                }



}
```

In this way i have done json parsing but i want to know how to fetch data from amazon web server and what are the things to required for amazon web server.please give me detail step by step.so that i can easily done.
i want to implement through aws web service s3 amazon web server for list view
i don't know how to implement
thanks in advance

Comment: you need to provide your amazon web-service details as well

Comment: i want to know how to do like json parsing or something else?give me format .generally i want to fetch the data from amazons3 server and that data show in list view.

Comment: this apps for encyclopedia we want to impliment tect_term_of_the_day so that we want to fetch all tech term of the day and that data store in the sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach you can use AWS Java API http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-java/ or AWS mobile API http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/ and not deal with JSON serialization at all.

Here you can find tutorial for work with S3: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Mobile/3002109349624271

Comment: i have also one problem i.e. i write some string in string.xml and that string is show in text view.through this i want to bold the particular string so what i do in string.xml but before today i applied <b>choudhary</b> so pls help me out

Comment: You need to modify properties of text view to make it bold. You have styles there, etc.